# ApplePay `paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:handler:` not called in Xcode Simulator 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applepay, passkit

ApplePay's **PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate** method `paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:handler:` is not being called when run on an Xcode 10.3 simulator.

This method is called as expected when built to a device with Xcode 10.3.

This method is called as expected in the Xcode 10.2.1 simulator.

The deprecated method `paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:completion:` exhibits the same negative behavior.

Based on the fact that it works on device and in older versions of Xcode, I'm certain my implementation is correct unless I'm missing something that changed. Does anyone know how to fix this for the Xcode 10.3 simulator?

Comment: @matt Testing on a device is not always possible. It worked on the simulator in the previous version of Xcode so I would expect it to still work on the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Well, lots of things work only on a device. It’s annoying and it might be a bug. I still don’t see where there is a Stack Overflow question concealed in what you’re saying.

Comment: When it comes to payment testing, it's recommended to test on physical device instead. I encoutered several case even didAuthorizePayment:handler: is invoked, token returned is empty so it's useless to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Xcode 11.3.